# Generating html directive

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a directive that will generate the HTML elements automatically according to data that received from the server.

Here is angularjs code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("workPlan").directive("myGenericFilter", ["$compile", "$http", "config", myGenericFilterData]);

    function myGenericFilterData($compile, $http, config) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                filterParams: "=filterparameters",
            },

            //templateUrl: config.baseUrl + "app/workPlan/templates/workPlanList.tmpl.html",
            template: '<div></div>',
            controller: "genericFilterDataController",
            controllerAs: "filter",

            link: function (scope, element) {
                var parameters;

                var el = angular.element('<span/>');
                $http.post(config.baseUrl + "api/FilterConfigurations/", scope.filterParams).then(function (result) {
                    parameters = result.data;
                    angular.forEach(parameters, function (parameter, key) {
                        switch (parameter.ValueType) {
                            case 'Int32':
                                el.append('<div class="form-group">' +
                                           '<div class="">' +
                                              '<span class="view"></span>' +
                                              '<input type="text"' + 'id =' + parameter.ObjectName + ' class="form-control">' +
                                           '</div>' +
                                           '</div>');
                                break;
                            case 'DateTime':
                                el.append('<div class="form-group">' +
                                               '<span class="view"></span>' +
                                               '<my-datepicker placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class=""></my-datepicker>' +
                                           '</div>');
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                });
                $compile(el)(scope);
                element.append(el);
            }
        }
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

As you can see I get data from server and according to `parameter.ValueType` appropriate case selected in the switch.

After the `angular.forEach` operator iterated on all items in the `parameters` variable and all DOM elements is loaded, all input HTML elements displayed except `my-datepicker` custom directive.
When I use F12 to **Inspect Element** I see the HTML code of all the elements(include `my-datepicker`).

Here how it's looks:

[image]

But in the view `my-datepicker` not displayed, here how it looks in view:

[image]

`my-datepicker` is custom directive that defined in common module that injected  in all moduls in  my project.

Any idea why `my-datepicker`  not displayed in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compile `el` before the content of `el` is setted. 
Remember that $http request is async then put

```
$compile(el)(scope);
element.append(el);
```

Into the callback

```
 link: function (scope, element) {
    var parameters;

    var el = angular.element('<span/>');
    $http.post(config.baseUrl + "api/FilterConfigurations/", scope.filterParams).then(function (result) {
        parameters = result.data;
        angular.forEach(parameters, function (parameter, key) {
            switch (parameter.ValueType) {
                case 'Int32':
                    el.append('<div class="form-group">' +
                               '<div class="">' +
                                  '<span class="view"></span>' +
                                  '<input type="text"' + 'id =' + parameter.ObjectName + ' class="form-control">' +
                               '</div>' +
                               '</div>');
                    break;
                case 'DateTime':
                    el.append('<div class="form-group">' +
                                   '<span class="view"></span>' +
                                   '<my-datepicker placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class=""></my-datepicker>' +
                               '</div>');
                    break;
            }
         });

       $compile(el)(scope);
       element.append(el);
    });
}
```

Comment: OK,but why input html displayed ?

Comment: If we look at the step, in the ordre : 1) $http.post, 2) compile `el`, 3) append `el` to the dom, 4) append HTML content to `el` (your input)
That's why you see the html input.